# Jasper : Multi level report

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I have my domain objects hierarchy as below:

[image: House Object Hierarchy]

As clear from above image, House object has a list of Room. Room object has a list of Windows and Windows object has a list of doors.

I will pass House object to my jrxml through a map.

I want to design my jrxml to output below report which has House as the top group, Room as sub group, Windows as sub group to Room sub group and finally Doors as sub group to Windows.

[image: Output Report Design]

How can I achieve such a level of sub grouping in Jasper?

Can some one please point me to some similar example on the internet ?

Thanks for reading!

Comment: did you try making groups in the report like what you mentioned the question ?

Comment: @Downvoter : Please explain the down voting atleast..

Comment: @cjava: Yes.. but I do not know how to put in the values inside the group correctly from the single object which I am passing to jrxml..